# c++14: Templated boost static visitor

Tags: c++, templates, boost, c++14

I'm implementing a templated boost static visitor that I want to use to return a type.
The visitor will be templated with one type and should throw an error for all other files.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <stdexcept>


#include <boost/variant/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/variant/static_visitor.hpp>

using namespace std;

template<class Type>
struct GetValue : public boost::static_visitor<Type>
{
    template<class Other>
    Type operator()(Other&& o) const
    {
        cout << "called some exception" << endl;
        throw std::runtime_error("error");
    }
    Type operator()(Type& t) const
    {
        cout << "called correct" << endl;
        return std::forward<Type>(t);
    }
};

template<class S>
struct Foo : public boost::variant<S, std::string>
{
    template <class Type>
    Foo(Type&& t)
     : boost::variant<Type, std::string>(std::forward<Type>(t))
     {}

    S operator*() const
    {
        return boost::apply_visitor(GetValue<S>{}, *this);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo<int> f = 5;
    auto foo = *f;
    return 0;
}
```

From what I understand, and sorry if I miss up the terminology, my first operator is a perfect forwarding reference and all calls will be sent there. However, my template type "Type" has already been expanded upon instantiation of the GetValue and thus no calls that I want match the second one that returns the type.

What definition do I need so that when I'm applying the visitor the function I want is called instead of everything referring to the default template.

This is the MVCE: https://godbolt.org/z/T5gd6m
I'm compiling in visual studio 2017 c++14.

Comment: In the new version of your code that you just pasted, `*this` is a const lvalue expression, that's why it does't bind to `Type&`. And it's still unclear what your actual problem is.

Comment: My question is what definition I need for *this to call the called correct operator.

Comment: `const Type& t`, and don't use `std::forward` on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you want to provide an overload that can win overload resolution with a forwarding reference (that is, an lvalue reference `Type&` parameter), you can exclude the unwanted function from consideration through SFINAE:

```
#include <boost/type_traits.hpp>

template <class Type>
class GetValue : public boost::static_visitor<Type>
{
public:
    template <class Other>
    auto operator()(Other&& o) const
        -> typename boost::disable_if<boost::is_same<typename boost::decay<Other>::type, Type>, Type>::type
    {
        throw error("Nope.");
    }
    Type operator()(const Type& t) const
    {
        return t;
    }
};
```

[**DEMO**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/JVZBIkzaRzKJLwL9)

Comment: It seems like this solves my problem.
Now up to understanding it enough to apply it to my pretty similar but different templates.
Thanks.

Comment: @turoni This answer was based on your previous code. Eventually, you don't need to use SFINAE at all, as `const Type&` wins overload resolution against `Other&&` due to the fact that the latter is a function template, and the former is not.